# Using std::queue with shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, stl, include, std, shared-ptr

Consider the following bit of code:

```
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<char> oneSharedPtr(new char[100]);

std::queue<std::shared_ptr<char>> stringQueue;
stringQueue.queue(oneSharedPtr);
```

This results in

```
error C2274: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator
```

Why is this? Is it safe to use shared pointers in queues (will the shared pointer's ref count go to 0 on a pop)?

Comment: `shared_ptr` is not used correctly in this case. It will call `delete ptr;` and not `delete[] ptr;`. You could replace your char array by a simple string...

Comment: @JBL This is a contrived example. I actually need to store a handle to a non null terminated buffer of in memory. How should one go handling such a case where the array delete should be called? Put it in a std::vector?

Comment: @JBL Looks like [boost::shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) is the array delete replacement for std::shared_ptr. Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: Just for the sake of completion. A std::shared_ptr to a std::vector would achieve as much.

Comment: Well you could try to use an `std::string` and its [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) member function. You could also use a [`shared_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) from Boost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because [std::queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) has no `queue` method. You are probably after `std::queue::push`.

```
stringQueue.push(oneSharedPtr);
```

**Note**: Your use of `std::shared_ptr` here is incorrect, since you are passing a newed array. There are a few ways to fix this:

1) Pass a deleter that calls `delete[]`:

```
std::shared_ptr<char> oneSharedPtr(new char[100], 
                                   [](char* buff) { delete [] buff; } );
```

2) Use an array-like type for which the `delete` works:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::array<char,100>> oneSharedPtr1(new std::array<char,100>());
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>> oneSharedPtr2(new std::vector<char>);
std::shared_ptr<std::string> oneSharedPtr3(new std::string());
```

3) Use [`boost::shared_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm)

```
boost::shared_array<char> oneSharedArray(new char[100]);
```

Comment: Right. I shall wear the [cone of shame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R58kSuIhURI). My fault for not checking up on the doc. How about the ref count on pop?

Comment: @UberMongoose the ref count will decreased, no surprises there. But look at JBL's comment. This is important.

Comment: @UberMongoose I added an example for `boost::shared_array`.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean

```
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

int main(){
std::shared_ptr<char> oneSharedPtr(new char[100]);

std::queue<std::shared_ptr<char>> stringQueue;
stringQueue.push(oneSharedPtr);
}
```

?
`std::queue` doesn't have `queue` method. Use always [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) for example to check what is available  : d

http://ideone.com/dx34N8